# Download and Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I would like to download a .CSV and redirect the user to another page.

This is my code

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + Request.QueryString["exportName"] + ".csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        //CODE TO WRITE CSV
        List<Company> companies = (List<Company>)Session["SelectedCompanies"];
        foreach (Company company in companies)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(company.Name + ";");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        }



        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("otherpage.aspx", true);


    }
```

But unfortunatly, it does only the redirect and not the download of the .CSV.

And if I replace `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("otherpage.aspx", true);` by `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`, then it does only the download of the .CSV and not the redirect.

But I would like to have both.

Comment: Download via ajax and on success function perform the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such cases, what I do is :

1. have an iframe hidden

   < iframe id="DownloadIFrame" visible="false" width="1" height="1" style="display:none" >
     < /iframe >
2. give this Iframe the url of my downlood (like download.ashx) while changing the content of my page.

*On the server*

```
public string DownloadViaIFrame(Page page, Download download)
        {
            string script = string.Format(
            @"
            var IsDownloaded=false;

            domReady(function() {{
                if (document.getElementById('DownloadIFrame')==undefined)
                                alert('DownloadIFrame not found');
                            else
                            {{
                                if (!IsDownloaded)
                                {{
                                    {0};
                                    IsDownloaded=true;
                                }}
                            }}
            }});", GetJavasciptToDownloadViaIFrame(download));


            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, typeof(Page), "download", script, true);

            return script;
        }


 public string GetJavasciptToDownloadViaIFrame(Download download)
        {
            return string.Format("document.getElementById('DownloadIFrame').src='{0}'", GetDownloadLink(download));
        }
```

this way the Iframe hit the download script on the server and gives back the file to be downloaded by the client. The client at the same time sees the content of its page changed and is happy..

good luck,

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this two actions couldn't be done in one request, either you redirect user either give file. Try to make it in two actions instead.

Answer (score 0):

as i know, no way making both actions.
Try redirect to otherPage.aspx,and inject a javascript code in otherPage.aspx that at onload event connect to a specific "real" download page